# How to find max negative number and min positive number in array

Tags: ruby

Are there some methods that can find max negative number and min positive number in array?
Array contains no zeros

```
[-1,5,-4,6,1,8,-3].max_negative # => -1
[-1,5,-4,6,1,8,-3].min_positive # => 1
```

Comment: Interesting question, but I think you should write "and" rather than "or".

Comment: You said in a comment that the array contains no zeroes. That is important and therefore should have been said in the question. I suggest you edit to add that, but make it clear that it's an edit (e.g., "Edit: I forgot to mention that the array contains no zeroes.").

Comment: [Please do NOT put "Edit" or "Update" tags in the text.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255685/128421) We can tell what changed when if we need to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in solution. But you can achieve that very simply.

```
[-1,5,-4,6,1,8,-3].select{|n| n < 0}.max # => -1
[-1,5,-4,6,1,8,-3].select{|n| n >= 0}.min # => 1
```

You can even wrap them in a method if you want, maybe in array class.

Answer (score 6):

```
[-1,5,-4,6,1,8,-3].select(&:negative?).max
[-1,5,-4,6,1,8,-3].select(&:positive?).min
```

Comment: Note these methods were added to Numeric in Ruby 2.3

Answer (score 4):

```
neg_max, pos_min =  [-1,5,-4,6,1,8,-3].minmax_by{|el| 1.0/el}
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Adding a zero to the array results in [-1,0] (because 1.0/0 is Infinity). This may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: @CarySwoveland array is zero-free..so this works too

Comment: This only works if the array contains at least a negative and a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this - partition the array into positive and negative sub-arrays and then find max/min from each of those two arrays.

```
positives, negatives = arr.partition(&:positive?)
p positives.min
#=> 1
p negatives.max
#=> -1
```

Alternatively, you could do as below, where array is sorted and a pair is found where first element of pair is negative and second element is positive, thus giving us the values of max negative and min positive values.

```
max_neg, min_pos = arr.sort.each_slice(2)
                           .select {|i, j| i.negative? and j.positive?}.flatten
```

Comment: The OP is looking for the "positive min" (1) and the "negative max" (-1). Also note that `0` is neither `positive?` nor `negative?`

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the comment.  Have updated the answer